# KVM VMs get disconnected when I restart a VM

Tags: kvm, qemu, bridge, libvirt, vlan

So, I have a VLAN setup in a KVM host, where I bridge a firewall WAN port to a physical eth interface, and then bridge the LAN port to an internal bridge, which has vlan subinterfaces, which themselves are slaves for bridges where VMs are connected.
The firewall LAN port has tagged VLANs.
I want the VMs to be connected to the right VLAN without having to tag their interfaces inside the VM, hence the intermediate bridges below.

Setup works and looks like this:

```
                                                                               +---------+   +--------+
                                                                               | Bridge  |   |        |
                 +----------+    +---------+    +--------+-+------------+      | br10    +---+  VM1   |
                 |          |    |         |    |        | | VLAN 10    +------+         |   |        |
+----------+     |          |    |         |    |        +-+------------+      +---------+   +--------+
|ethernet  +-----+  Bridge  +----+FIREWALL +----+  Bridge  |
+----------+     |          |    |         |    |   Int  +-+------------+      +---------+   +--------+
                 |          |    |         |    |        | | VLAN 20    +------+ Bridge  |   |        |
                 +----------+    +---------+    +--------+-+------------+      | br20    +---+  VM2   |
                                                                               |         |   |        |
                                                                               +---------+   +--------+
```

So far so good, everything works until I reboot the firewall.
The vnet tun interfaces that are connected to the VLAN bridges just disconnect from the bridge (eg if VM2 has vnet3 and is connected to br20, vnet3 disappears from bridge br20 once I reboot the firewall).

Of course I can reconnect them by identifiying them with something like

```
for vm in $(virsh list --name); do echo "$vm: $(virsh dumpxml $vm | grep vnet)"; done
```

Then connecting them with

```
ip link set vnet3 master br20
```

But I'd love to know why my VM interfaces disconnect from my bridges, and perhaps find a way for them to "stay" after a firewall reboot.

Anyone has an idea how to achieve this ?